# Android split error in date picker

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Good day everyone! Im creating a hotel booking mobile application and most of the module I need is to set check in and check out. I want to set mindate of checkout being selected from the check-in date picker. I found an error in getting the value of the selected date in check in. Can someone help me?

```
   etin = findViewById(R.id.etcheckin);
    etin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    etout = findViewById(R.id.etcheckout);
    etout.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    etin.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showTruitonDatePickerDialog(view);

        }
    });

    etout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showToDatePickerDialog(view);

        }
    });
}

public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void  showToDatePickerDialog(View v){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ToDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public static class  DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert, this, year, month, day);

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        c.set(2018,11 ,31);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month , int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month - 0 +1 , day);

        etin.setText(month+1 + "/" + day + "/" + year);
        etout.setText(month+ 1 + "/" + day + "/" + year);

        String monthString = null;
        String [] monthsTemp = {"Jan", "Feb","March","April","May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

        if (month == 0) {
            monthString = monthsTemp[0];
        }
        else if (month == 1){
            monthString = monthsTemp[1];
        }
        else if (month == 2){
            monthString = monthsTemp[2];
        }

        else if (month == 3){
            monthString = monthsTemp[3];
        }

        else if (month == 4){
            monthString = monthsTemp[4];
        }

        else if (month == 5){
            monthString = monthsTemp[5];
        }

        else if (month == 6){
            monthString = monthsTemp[6];
        }

        else if (month == 7){
            monthString = monthsTemp[7];
        }

        else if (month == 8){
            monthString = monthsTemp[8];
        }

        else if (month == 9){
            monthString = monthsTemp[9];
        }

        else if (month == 10){
            monthString = monthsTemp[10];
        }

        else{
            monthString = monthsTemp[11];
        }

        etin.setText(monthString + "/" + day + "/" + year);

    }
}

public static class ToDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       String getfromdate = etin.getText().toString();
      String getfrom[] = getfromdate.split("/");

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year,month,day;
        year= Integer.parseInt(getfrom[2]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[0]);
       day = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[1]);

        c.set(year, month, day + 1);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert, this, year, month, day);

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

        c.set(2018,11, 31);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;

    }
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month , day);

        etout.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month).append("/").append(day).append("/").append(year));


    }
}
```

Comment: It might help if we knew the expected output vs what you’re actually seeing.

Comment: you are doing a lot of heavy lifting that is totally unnecessary. Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format your dates. From your code I can not see if you are allowing the user to enter the dates manually. For your sake (ultimately the users sake) do not allow them to enter date data through the keyboard. Clean up your code and you will not need `split`

Comment: the user can select date from check in edittext but when it comes to check out the application has stopped. 

if I use simple date format, how can i set the mindate of checkout datepicker from selected date of checkin?